# LWP::UserAgent retrieve file date and time from ftp directory listing

Tags: perl, ftp

I am trying to retrieve the last modified time of files on a remote ftp site as follows:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $index = $ua->get($ftp); # where $ftp contains the url to the ftp-folder of interest
print $index->decoded_content;
```

However this prints the contents of the remote as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user group  size Month Date Year filename
```

I would like to have the contents to include *hour:minute:seconds* formatted like 'ls -l':

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  group size Year-Month-Date hour:minute:seconds filename
```

How can I do this?

**Answer:**

Thanks to the accepted answer below I understand that get() gives response of `LIST`, where `MLSD` has all information I need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

my $host=$ARGV[0];
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) or die "Can't open $host\n";
$ftp->login;
my @mlsd=$ftp->_list_cmd("MLSD",".") or die "MLSD failed:",$ftp->message;
for my $content (@mlsd) {
    next unless (index($content, "type=file") != -1);
    my @info = split ";",$content;
    my $filename=$info[5];
    (my $filesize = $info[1]) =~ s/size=//g;
    (my $filedate=$info[2]) =~ s/modify=//g;
    $filedate =~ s/^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\z/$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6/s;
    printf ("%-20s %10s %11s\n",$filename,$filesize,$filedate);
}
$ftp->quit;
exit;
```

Would of course be nice if this could be achieved with `LWP::UserAgent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get is the raw output of an FTP `LIST` command. Unfortunately, the output format of this command isn't standardized. But you can get the modification time with the `MDTM` command. This isn't supported by `LWP::UserAgent` so you have to use `Net::FTP` directly:

```
use Net::FTP;

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host);
$ftp->login;

for my $file ($ftp->ls) {
    next if $file eq '.' || $file eq '..';

    my $time = $ftp->mdtm($file); # UNIX timestamp
    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime($time);
    printf(
        "$file: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
        $year + 1900, $mon + 1, $mday,
        $hour, $min, $sec,
    );
}
```

Comment: I did not realize that get() gave the response of `LIST`. This solution makes me request the timestamp file by file, while I would like to have the information in one request. Turns out the FTP-server I connect to supports `MSLD`.  This answer gave me the hint to the final solution.